# Moq C# Callback can we get List/Collection for callback parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, callback, moq

```
var callArgs = new List<string>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(true)
    .Callback((string s) => callArgs.Add(s));
```

Similarly can we do Callback for List parameter

```
var callArgs = new List<string>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething(It.IsAny<List<string>>()))
    .Returns(true)
    .Callback((List<string> s) => callArgs.AddRange(s));
```

Is this possible somehow if not why?

var ex = new List();
myrMock.Setup(x => x.foo(It.IsAny>(), It.IsAny>(), It.IsAny()))
               .Callback((IList sy, IList v,string str) => ex.AddRange(sy));

I am not getting anything in ex list.

Comment: Did you give it a try?

Comment: i tried ... i m getting below error:

Comment: Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters (IList`1,IList`1,String) cannot invoke callback with parameters (List`1).

Comment: then the type of your argument in `Foo()` is `IList<string>`? If so, the type of your callback must match the type of your argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, exactly as you described.

Or you can use this format:

```
var callArgs = new List<string>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething(It.IsAny<List<string>>()))
    .Returns(true)
    .Callback<List<string>>(s => callArgs.AddRange(s));
```

https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart